# iPhone/iPad Flipboard Page Turn Animation?

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation

I want to make an animation that is exactly the same as the Flipboard's one. I have tested  [Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves) and [EPGLTransitionView](https://github.com/epatel/EPGLTransitionView) on github, however, Leaves gives me the hand gesture but doesn't implement the page turn animation (its animation is like the iBook's one), and EPGLTransitionView doesn't implement the hand gestures.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Sincerely,

Kai.

Answer (score 6):

This github project might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/Dillion/iOS-Flip-Transform.